# A counterexample for a theorem of integral of inverse function

Tags: integration, continuity, inverse-function

**Question:** For $a<b$, let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$ and injective.

(a) Show that $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx+\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(y) dy=bf(b)-af(a).$$

(b) Investigate whether the previous equality holds when assuming that the function $f$ is continuous and injective on $[a,b]$ only.

**What I did:** For part a, I define a function as $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt+\int_{f(a)}^{f(x)} f^{-1}(y) dy$ and proved that it is equal to $xf(x)-af(a)$ by using FTC and $F(a)=0$. However, I don't even know where I did use that $f$ is "continuously differentiable". So, how can I give a counterexample for part b? (I am just assuming that being continuous is not enough, it is just an interpretation I make by looking the format of the question.)

Comment: When you used FTC, did you differentiate $xf(x)$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, actually, I said $F'(x)=f(x)+f'(x)f^{-1}\left (f(x)\right)=f(x)+xf'(x)=\left (xf(x)\right)'$ by FTC. However, how did I used that $f'(x)$ is continuous? This is where I don't understand.

Comment: Just check with a counterexample at which step your proof fails. e.g. take $f:[0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x, & x\in [0,1] \\ 2x-1, & x\in[1,2]\end{cases}$$ which is continuous and injective on $[a,b] = [0,2]$ but it holds $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx+\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(y) dy=8.25 \not= 6 = bf(b)-af(a)$$

Comment: @Gono So $$f^{-1}(y) = \begin{cases}y, & y \in [0,1] \\ (y+1)/2, & y \in [1,3]\end{cases}$$
and $$\int_0^2 f(x)\,dx = 2.5 \\ \int_0^3 f^{-1}(y)\,dy = 3.5$$ I don't know how you found $8.25$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring You are right… accidentally took $f(b) = 4$ instead of $3$… my fault.